# emergency: update 1 fragment from viewpager having two fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have one viewpager in main activity. Inside viewpager, I have 2 fragments A and B. Fragment A has a listview of news topic. And when you click each item on listview, the content of news is gonna show on fragment B. 
My idea is  setcurrentitem() right in listview adapter whenever clicking on each item. But I find out it doesn't work. Fragment B does NOT show content from second news on listview at Fragment A. It means that viewpager does not update content for Fragment B

Someone can tell me how I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: do you have any idea to update fragment B by touching an item in fragment A? I searched a lot in google but it doesn't work. Pls help

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use external inteface to pass data between activity and fragment. You shouldn't talk between fragments directly, use Activity as a proxy. Example below:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements InteractionInterface {

    private ViewPager viewPager;

    private MyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle instance) {
        super.onCreate(instance);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private FragmentA fragmentA;

        private FragmentB fragmentB;

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            fragmentA = new FragmentA();
            fragmentB = new FragmentB();
        }

        @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return position == 0 ? fragmentA : fragmentB;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        // this comes from InteractionInterface
        if(adapter.fragmentB.isAdded()) {
            adapter.fragmentB.doSomething("yeah!!");
        }
    }

}
```

FragmentA.java

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    private Button button;

    private InteractionInterface interface = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                if(interface != null) {
                    // you can modify this interface to pass some data
                    interface.onClick(); 
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onAttach(Activity a) {
        super.onAttach(a);
        if (a instanceof InteractionInterface) {
            interface = (InteractionInterface) a;
        }
    }

    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        interface = null;
    }

}
```

FragmentB.java

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    ...

    public void doSomething(String something) {
        // do stuff here
    }

}
```

InteractionInterface.java

```
public interface InteractionInterface {
    void onClick();
}
```

Comment: It works better than good. Honest to say, thank you so much. I got confused this problems for some days and you made my day. Have a good day guy..

Comment: You're welcome :) Please accept my answer if you like it